# Why am I able to execute a file which has just read permission?

Tags: command-line, scripts, sh

I am able to execute a file which has just read permission:

```
nkrish@maddev2:~$ ls -l NewFile.sh 
-r--r--r-- 1 nkrish nkrish 14 2016-01-14 12:01 NewFile.sh

sh NewFile.sh
.. File gets run...
```

Shouldn't file permissions' be `r-x` in order for this to execute?

Currently user's permission is readonly (`r--`).

Why is this?

Comment: It's asked in the second point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing `NewFile.sh`, your are executing the command `sh`, likely `/bin/sh` passing it `NewFile.sh` as an argument.

`sh` happens to read what is in this file and execute it. It doesn't check for execution permission by design, assuming you know what you are doing.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't work if you did `./NewFile.sh`.

Comment: @user4901968 Indeed although that's not the question asked.